# Accessing property of nested object throwing Typescript error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object that I'm trying to type, and the object seems to not have any issues, it's when I try to access a nested property that I get the dreaded red squiggle.

I've done some looking around and I've found multiple posts suggesting an approach similar to this:

```js
type FlagValue = string | boolean | number | { [key: string]: FlagValue };
type FlagSet = { [key: string]: FlagValue | FlagSet};

const defaultFlags: FlagSet = {
  tracking: false,
  banner: {
    display: false,
    message: "I am the man with no name, Zapp Brannigan!",
  },
  theme: "dark",
};
```

and it seems to work fine as far as typing the object goes, but where I run into issues is when I try to access any of the nested properties

[image: const showBanner = defaultFlags.banner.display;]

...

```
Property 'display' does not exist on type 'FlagValue | FlagSet'.
  Property 'display' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiAbAhgcwGpYYCuqAvHAN5wDaA1sIgFxwDOMUAlgHY4C6zmXAWKoAvnAA+rdtxyS4AIwgQMwLF3lciAWwXAocANwBYAFChIsBMlSCcAZWAwAPABU45O8JIA+D5Rp6JmlOHn44dyk7RxhRE1MzC2h4AGMILjY4ABNgADMsIgwYOxYBbAcnfwozOAQoLBTaWWZ8jBZgABoaxXUufWZq01rarI4WMGxg1vauoeHtYBYWXGBmACIASTgsbQQAC1RtdTgAdw4YPbguCCudzrgALSwwMDgAIXquLg4cdQBCNazWqiIH7YALdZZLBQWiAsxxMyIhKmJAoCLeMiKZSqY5SLS6fSaHR6KDUXjxVGoVwAESwMCwbyqgQYzDYoT4zFcGPkNLpDLgCORSSsaQy8Fy5VKEVp9MZ5EGtXYDSaPBahBm3QgRHpOGAb16-Uo3RGYwmWCm6s63RB8PiZlFmRYewgJ31X0J5By+UKxUlADoFAaoH7RuNJvEHfAnS63X0oABGfwS3AsANBkOm8NAA)

Answer (score -1):

Well `defaultFlags.banner` is typed as:

```
string | boolean | number | { [key: string]: FlagValue }
```

So you have to prove the value is object before you try to treat it like one:

```
const showBanner =
   typeof defaultFlags.banner === 'object'
      ? defaultFlags.banner.display
      : false
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQwOYDUFwK7QLxQM7ABOAlgHZJQA+UARgPZ1wQKlVSkYC2NEhbA3lADaAawggAXPiJkkAXSnxkaTNAC+AbgBQoSLERIAyhGBRcg0eKkES5BfuXosbJUZOatWgMZ1SBKAAmEABmCBhwwK54igbGpuZaUFBECF4islKhcHgQADSJtCykvFL8BUkBxHhgiJJQWTn5SUmcEHh4yBBSAEQAklAInMkAFtCcLFAA7sTAw+x07IN5UABaCGBgUABChEXESCwAhN1NUGqnsxCtPQEIhCInWmqePn6meMN0k1tFvGbluggdGCgRCYQiUQAdDRfnxsPCoAByOg0ABWEC8wER5WaAH5QaFwpEDHhobDIZVqrUcUlMugckA)

---

Alternatively, you can change your declaration to use `satisfies`. This will enforce the constraint of `FlagSet`, while preserve the inferred type from the assinged object literal.

```
const defaultFlags = {
  tracking: false,
  banner: {
    display: false,
    message: "I am the man with no name, Zapp Brannigan!",
  },
  theme: "dark",
} satisfies FlagSet

const showBanner = defaultFlags.banner.display
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQwOYDUFwK7QLxQM7ABOAlgHZJQA+UARgPZ1wQKlVSkYC2NEhbA3lADaAawggAXPiJkkAXSnxkaTNAC+AbgBQoSLERIAyhGBRcg0eKkES5BfuXosbJUZOatWgMZ1SBKAAmEABmCBhwwK54ZlD8WlBQRAheIrJSoXB4EAA08bQspLxScQkJAcR4YIiSUBlZuaVQnBB4eMgQUgBEAJJQCJyJABbQnCxQAO7EwIPsdOz9OVAAWghgYFAAQoQFxEgsAISdDVBqx9MQzV0BCIQiR1pq+AjAFcHELQ5uwJ4+fqZ4gzo4w2BV4MSCoXCkQMeAAdDRQYRYeVKtUgA)